# Speed Up Program Below

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, loops, filter

I have written this for loop program below where I go through element by element of an array and do some math to those elements. Once the math is calculated it gets stored into another array.

```
for i in range(0, 1024): 
   x[i] = a * data[i]+ b * x[(i-1)] + c * x[(i-2)]
```

So in my program a, b, and c are just scalar numbers. Data and x are arrays. Data has an array size 1024 filled with numbers in each element. X is also an array size 1024 but it's filled with all zeros initially. In order to calculate the new elements of x I use the previous two elements of x. Initially the previous two are 0 and 0 since it takes the last two element from the x array of zeros. I multiply the current element of data by a, the last element of x by b, and the second to last element of x by c. Then I add everything up and save it to the current element of x. Then I do the same thing for every element in data and x.

This loop program works but I was wondering if there is a faster way to do it? Maybe using a combination of numpy functions like cumsum or dot product? Can some one help me maybe make the program faster? Thank you!

Comment: It seems that this will fail - you get negative indices for i=0 and 1

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Numpy arrays might be faster even  with the loop

Comment: If you’re looking for feedback/suggestions on working code, then https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is the more appropriate place to post.

Comment: Numpy is good option to get faster

Comment: You don't have to worry about negative indices since I defined x = np.zeros(1024) before the loop. So x[-1] = 0 and x[-2] = 0 regardless since in numpy arrays if you take the negative index of an array it works backwards. The loop doesn't fails at all. I just want to know if there is a way to write it without a for loop?

Answer (score 1):

Best you could do using recursive method:

```
x = a * data
coef = np.array([c,b])
for i in range(2, 1024): 
   x[i] += np.dot(coef, x[i-2:i])
```

But even better, you can solve this recurrence equation to a closed form solution and apply directly without loop. (This is a basic 2nd order linear equation)

Comment: How would you solve the recurrence equation to get a closed form solution?

Comment: This link could help https://brilliant.org/wiki/linear-recurrence-relations/ or a google will also point you in a right direction.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you want a programm that is fast, Python is not the best option. Python is great for prototyping since it is easy and has a lot of tools, however it is not verry computationally efficient in it's raw form if you compare it to for example C. What I usually do is to use Cython, is is a module for python that let's you convert your script to machiene code (as you do with C) which would greatly increase the speed of the appliation.

It let's you type cast the variables for example:

`cdef double a, b, c`

When you use a variable in Python the variables has to be checked every single time to make sure what type of variable it is (int, double, string etc). In C, that is not an issue since you have to decide from the start what the variable should be, decreasing the time consumption of the operation.

Answer (score -1):

I would try to transform the for loop in a list comprehension which has much faster processing time in python.